# Not able to render the new component on onClick()

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and facing some problem while rendering a new component on onClick() on a table cell item.

```
class Component extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.routeChange = this.routeChange.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            values: []
        };
    }
routeChange(id) {
        console.log(id)
        const userAccount = (
            <Account  />
          );
        return userAccount;
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div className="classname1">
                <table>
                    <thead className="table-header">
                        <tr className="table-row">
                            <th>Account Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.values.map(value => {
                            return (
                             <tr className="data-table">
                                <td className="txt-blue" onClick={() => this.routeChange(value.id)}>{value.name}</td>
                             </tr>)
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

}
```

So when I execute the above everything works fine and the table has been rendered properly but when I click on the table cell item then my  component is not being rendered. But I can see the console.log() which I have passed in routeChange().

Note: My state values[] is not empty because as here I am only showing the snippet of my code.

Comment: You're looping around this.state.values, and each iteration is 'value'. You need to pass 'value.id' as the argument to the onClick function. At least, that's one of your problems. Not sure it will do that. To be sure though, console.log(id) in the onClick to make sure it's getting the value you're expecting.

Comment: @rrd Values is correct

Comment: If you're mapping through this.state.values, and each iteration is 'value', where's the 'values.value' coming from?

Comment: @rrd It was a typo error updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference of a function that calls `routeChange` function to the `onClick` function. One way to do this is to use an arrow function.

```
<td className="txt-blue" onClick={() => this.routeChange(values.value.id)}>{values.value.name}</td>
```

Comment: I have already tried with arrow function but still same issue

Comment: @harihar you aren't passing a reference to the routeChange function, you are creating a function that calls it. I agree with this, but just wanted to let that be clear. Passing the routeChange reference would be `onClick={this.routeChange}`, which doesn't help here, but still

Comment: @AayushChachan can you please update your question when this change is made? You can't get the same error because that one is solved by what harihar proposed.

Comment: @tcanusso Sorry my bad. yes you are correct that error has been resolved but my routeChange() is not returning <Account /> component.

Comment: @HariharDas Thanks after adding arrow function that error was fixed

Comment: With your updated question and my answer is it working for you now?

Comment: @HariharDas No, your answer helped in resolvong "Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type" not my updated question

Comment: Have you looked at [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)? I think [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) will fit your use case.

Answer (score 1):

When you click and the event 'onClick' is triggered, it doesn't expect a return value, meaning that component you are returning is going nowhere.

What you can do to show the 'Account' component is keep a variable, say showAccount, in your state, which initialises as false, and with the method 'routeChange' what you do is change this to true.

I don't quite understand your use case, but something like this could be:

```
class Component extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.routeChange = this.routeChange.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            values: [],
            accountId: null,
            showAccount: false
        };
    }
routeChange(id) {
        console.log(id)
        /* Commenting this,
          const userAccount = (
            <Account  />
          );
          return userAccount;
        */
        this.setState({showAccount: true, accountId: id})
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div className="classname1">
                <table>
                    <thead className="table-header">
                        <tr className="table-row">
                            <th>Account Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.values.map(value => {
                            return (
                             <tr className="data-table">
                                <td className="txt-blue" onClick={() => this.routeChange(value.id)}>{value.name}</td>
                             </tr>)
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {this.state.showAccount && this.state.accountId &&
                  <Account id={this.state.accountId} />
                }
            </div>

}
```

Anyhow, try to play with your component and see what works best for you. What I suggest may not be useful for you, so just take the concept and adapt it for your own app.

Comment: But <Account /> component is rendering on the same page I want it to be rendered as a different page with different route. Can you share any link which can be a helpful to me?

Comment: You should then change your logic up a little bit, because you will need to add routes to a parent component, and make this tr's have links to the route you want. You should also take into account that you will need params (which you can pass as route params). You can read on this here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

ps. it was actually quite hard finding an example, so try using the examples from the official docs of react-router and learn by playing around, hope it helps!